# How to add plugin to eclipse , So that I can run QML from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, qml

How to add plug in to eclipse , So that I can run `QML` from Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Use the Momentics IDE from BlackBerry, which is built on Eclipse, but has integrated QML syntax highlighting and preview:

https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/download/

Comment: is it possible to install it as plug-in to existing instance of eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded QT developer and working on it. QT developer has QML editor ........ :)

Comment: What is QT developer can you give a link, please?

Comment: @Sergei I had installed from Ububtu software center, You try with this link http://qt-project.org/downloads